# tlmgr install document class package (refman)?

Tags: tlmgr

I'm trying to install `refman` class package via `tlmgr` (Ubuntu 14.04, non-system locations). So I did:

```
$ tlmgr install refman
TeX Live 2015 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: refman [666k]
tlmgr: package log updated: /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
```

At this point, there are `refman.ins`/`.dtx` in `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/source/latex/refman/`, but no `.cls`; so I do:

```
$ cd /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/source/latex/refman/
$ latex refman.ins
$ texhash
```

But after that, when I try to `pdflatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{refman}

\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

... I get:

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 33 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `refman.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: X
```

How can I get the refman document class to install properly?

Answer (score 2):

Eh, it turns out the `refman` package does not include a `refman.cls` class - instead the `latex *.ins` generates in `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/source/latex/refman/` files `refart.cls` and `refrep.cls` - and the same can be found in `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refman/`, which is where the LaTeX engine would look for them ( [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) )

So - it turns out that either of these two work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{refart}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{refrep}
```

... but there is no such thing as `\documentclass{refman}` - unfortunately, that cannot be quickly gleaned from `texdoc refman`.